# Justify text from a file using a LaTeX method

Tags: python, beginner, algorithm, formatting, dynamic-programming

I wrote a bit of code that takes a file, justifies the text and writes to another file.

It uses a DP approach to minimise a *badness* metric, which is the amount of undershoot of the line length, cubed (see my answer below, the badness function isn't quite right if there is an overshoot, the badness should be `inf` - I believe this is how LaTeX justifies its text).

I encapsulated it in a `class` (which is the bit I'm least confident about). Be careful running it on big files, because I think it's got a pretty nasty complexity (\$O(n^2)\$ maybe).

```
class justifyText:
    def __init__(self, inFileName, outFileName, pageWidth):
        with open(inFileName, "r") as fp:
            self.words = [word for line in fp for word in line.split()]
        self.outFileName = outFileName
        self.pageWidth = pageWidth
        self.memo = {}
        self.breakPointTrack = {}
        self.n = len(self.words)

    def badness(self, i, j):
        totalWidth = 0;
        for word in self.words[i:j]:
            totalWidth += len(word)
        return abs((self.pageWidth - totalWidth)**3)

    def minBadness(self, i):
        if i in self.memo:
            return self.memo[i]
        if i == self.n:
            f = 0
            j_min = self.n
        else:
            f = None
            for j in range(i + 1, self.n + 1):
                temp = self.minBadness(j) + self.badness(i, j)
                if (f is None) or (temp < f):
                    f = temp
                    j_min = j
        self.memo[i] = f
        self.breakPointTrack[i] = j_min
        return f

    def justify(self):
        self.minBadness(0)
        fOut = open(self.outFileName, "w")
        brk = 0
        while brk < self.n:
            start = brk
            brk = self.breakPointTrack[brk]
            line = " ".join(self.words[start:brk]) + "\n"
            fOut.write(line)
        fOut.close()

test = justifyText("test.txt", "out.txt", 80)
test.justify()
```

Is this a standard way to implement a DP program? I know that global variables are evil, so I was mainly trying to avoid my memo etc. being that.

Comment: I have rolled back Rev 4 → 3. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Comment: You dropped an `abs()` call in your `badness()` function that is mentioned in the answer. If you have found a bug, you can write an answer to your own question explaining what the bug is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should have a look at Python's official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). One of its recommendations is to use `PascalCase` for class names and `lower_case` for function and variable names.

Since you read all words into memory anyway, you can just write:

```
with open(in_file_name) as fp:
    self.words = fp.read().split()
```

This is because `split` splits by default on all whitespace (so both space and newlines). Also note that the default behaviour of `open` is to open a file in read mode, so `"r"` is also not needed here.

Caching (or memoization) of a functions return value is best done with a decorator. This way you avoid interleaving the actual implementation of the function with the caching. One example could be:

```
import functools


def memoize_method(func):
    cache = func.cache = {}

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self, n):
        if n not in cache:
            cache[n] = func(self, n)
        return cache[n]
    return wrapper


class JustifyText:
    ...
    @memoize_method
    def min_badness(self, i):
        if i == self.n:
            f, j_min = 0, self.n
        else:
            f, j_min = min((self.min_badness(j) + self.badness(i, j), j) 
                           for j in range(i + 1, self.n + 1))
        self.break_point_track[i] = j_min
        return f
```

Your `badness` function can be simplified by using `sum`, similar to how I used `min` above:

```
def badness(self, start, end):
    total_width = sum(len(word) for word in self.words[start:end])
    return abs((self.page_width - total_width)**3)
```

While it might be your most used use case, writing the output to a file prevents anyone from using this module in any other way. It would be better if `justify` just returned (even better and simpler: yielded) the justified text and writing to a file is left to the user or a dedicated method using `justify` internally.

```
def justify(self):
     self.min_badness(0)  # no-op or to populate the cache?
     brk = 0
     while brk < self.n:
         start, brk = brk, self.break_point_track[brk]
         yield " ".join(self.words[start:brk]) + "\n"

def write(self):
    with open(self.out_file_name, "w") as f_out:
        f_out.writelines(self.justify())
```

I'm not exactly sure why you have a lone `self.min_badness(0)` in `justify`. is it just to populate the cache with the value for zero? If so, this is worth to put a comment here, because otherwise you might accidentally delete it.

Comment: Great review. Thanks a lot. The `self.min_badness(0)` starts the recursive `self.min_badness()` at the start of the file, it should then take care of the rest of the file; stopping at the base case which is the end of the file in this case. Is there anywhere that explains the `@memoize_method` syntax that you use? I've seen this around, but I don't know what it's called or how it works.

Comment: Is that a so called decorator?

Comment: @Aidenhjj Yes that is a decorator. What it does is call `min_badness = memoize_method(min_badness)` after the definition of the function.

Comment: OK. So is `self` in your definition of `wrapper` an instance of `JustifyText`?

Comment: @Aidenhjj `self` is whatever is being passed onto the function. When you call it as `jt = JustifyText(...); jt.min_badness(0)` it will be `jt`. It basically just passes it along.

Comment: The advantage of `[word for line in fp for word in line.split()]` over `fp.read().split()` is that it doesn't use twice the amount of memory: once for reading the file, once for storing the list of words…

Comment: @MathiasEttinger True, I did not think of that.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger I don't actually think this is the case. Using [`memory_profiler`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler) on the code reports that both use roughly the same amount. ~6.5MiB using comp, ~6.7MiB using `.read`, for a 1MiB file. I also checked splitting `.read.split` to use an intermarry variable and it used ~7.4MiB. Honestly I think the, large, speed increase is worth the little extra memory.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Interesting tool, this `memory_profiler`. Using `mprof run` with a very small period revealed that the `split` used way more memory internally than the `read` or the list-comp. So using the fastest one (`read`) seems the best call. TIL.

Answer (score 4):

I realised that this code wasn't dealing correctly with the overshoots. I should have coded `badness()` as something like:

```
def badness(self, i, j):
    total_width = -1;
    for word in self.words[i:j]:
        total_width += len(word) + 1
    if total_width > self.page_width:
        return float("inf")
    return abs((self.page_width - total_width)**3)
```

Comment: +500 bounty on this answer has been awarded as a prize for [Best of Code Review 2016 — Best Newcomer (question)](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/7139/9357), since bounties cannot be awarded on questions.